# Annotation image not set as coded

Tags: iphone, mkannotationview

I wondered what is wrong here. The annotation is showing the default red pin. I have copied the image file into the project folder and checked the names.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView
            viewForAnnotation:(id)ann {

    NSString *identifier = @"myPin";
    MKPinAnnotationView *annView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)
    [aMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (annView == nil) {
        annView= [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:ann
                                               reuseIdentifier:identifier]
               autorelease];
    } else {
        annView.annotation = ann;
    }

    annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    UIImage *pinImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AnnotationIcon.png"];
    [annView setImage: pinImage];
    annView.enabled = YES;
    annView.animatesDrop=TRUE;
    annView.canShowCallout=YES;

    return annView;
}
```

Comment: Check for every object (if nil or not) with NSLog or breakpoints.

Comment: @Mundi Not sure if I am doing it right. But I do get "annView is <MKPinAnnotationView: 0xe0451a0;" "annImage is <UIImage: 0xe04e430>" "ann is <MyAnnotation: 0xe007d30>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researching, I found out that the MKPinAnnotationView - animatesDrop property cannot be used for custom images.